# Infopath filtering and repeat section

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have to create an Infopath form.  I have 2 lists in my SharePoint Online,

1. list Activities list all activities.
2. List Hazzard list all hazzards, per activity. (one activity = many hazzards)

So in Infopath, I create a dropdown list that shows activities, once the necessary activity has been selected a repetitive table list all Hazzards for that Activity. (upon selection of activity, I query the hazzard table to list all hazzards linked to that activity selected)

But this form needs to enable the user to select unlimited activities and each activity's hazzard should be listed.  So the above needs to be in a repetitive section.  But when I repeat the section and select activity in next section, it refreshes all activities and hazzards in all sections with the one selected. See problem underneath:  Activity 1 must remain on 'Compacting & Filing' and Activity 2 must filter newly selected activity Hazards.

[image]